# axios cannot override host when making HTTP GET request to traefik reverse proxy

Tags: docker, http, axios, traefik

Context: I'm using traefik as my reverse proxy to send HTTP requests to my backend Golang server, which I've added some CORS handling. It works from Postman and when I'm cURLing the HTTP GET request

[image]

Problem: I'm getting this 404 error on the browser:

[image]

Axios call overriding Host

```
axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost',
})

axios.defaults.headers['Host'] = 'dev.docker.local'
```

got this error in the console

```
refused to set unsafe header "Host"
```

Axios call overriding default Host using X-Host-Override

```
axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost',
})

axios.defaults.headers['X-Host-Override'] = 'dev.docker.local'
```

Axios call setting default headers - seems like it's always using localhost as the Host

```
axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost',
  headers: {'Host': 'dev.docker.local'}
})
```

[image]

set CORS in route handlers

```
func About(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")

    aboutStruct := about{
        Name: "Hello world",
    }
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    j, _ := json.Marshal(aboutStrcut)
    w.Write(j)
}
```

Comment: The 404 shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgews.png is for the CORS preflight OPTIONS request that the browser automatically makes on its own. The purpose for the preflight in this specific case is that the browser is asking the server for the `http://localhost/api/about` endpoint if it allows cross-origin requests with the `x-host-override` header. But the `http://localhost` server is for some reason responding to that request with a 404 — and not including and Access-Control-Allow-\* headers in that response, because like most servers it probably only adds those to 2xx responses.

Comment: So you need to make the backend of `http://localhost/api/about` instead respond to that preflight OPTIONS request with a 200 OK and with the necessary value in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header. If your current `w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")` is causing a literal `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` response header to be sent, then you need to change that, because browsers don’t currently support use of a wildcard there (it was added to the spec relatively recently). So you instead need to send `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-host-override`

Comment: same error when I did w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-host-override") :(

Comment: Right, because the server is responding with a 404 to all requests for `http://localhost/api/about`. I see now that https://i.stack.imgur.com/NICft.png shows it’s responding with a 404 to your GET request. So it’s not something specific to the OPTIONS request. As far as I can that 404 isn’t related to any of your CORS config.

Comment: I got that 404 because I think axios ignored the headers field when I did headers: {'Host': 'dev.docker.local'}, that's why in the picture it still says "localhost" for Host, is there anything else I could check?

Comment: The `Host` request header is a “forbidden header name” https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name. Browsers don’t allow you to set it from your frontend code; instead it’s something that browsers reserve for their own use — just like the `Origin` and `Referer` request headers. So that fact that you get a failure when you try to set it is expected.

Comment: i see, if it's not CORS and it's not the axios call, what can possibly be causing the 404 error now?

Comment: From what you’ve described the 404 is because you can neither send a request with the `Host` request header set to what the server expects nor with the `x-host-override` request header set to what the server expects. In the case of setting the `x-host-override` header, the browser first sends a preflight OPTIONS request to the server *without the `x-host-override` header included* — because the entire purpose of the preflight is for the browser to ask the server if it allows cross-origin requests that include the `x-host-override` header.

Comment: So I dunno but from what you’ve described it seems like you need to configure the server to treat requests from `http://localhost:3000` in the same way it treats requests from  `http://dev.docker.local`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found a way to solve this problem for the browser, needed to use dnsmasq to point docker.local to 127.0.0.1 and then set baseURL to dev.docker.local, no need to override Host